# Calculate ratio between all combinations of values in a row across two data sets

Tags: r

So as mentioned in the title I have two data sets:

data 1:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(18L, 19L, 5L, 13L, 14L, 31L
), .Label = c("AMC Javelin", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Camaro Z28", 
"Chrysler Imperial", "Datsun 710", "Dodge Challenger", "Duster 360", 
"Ferrari Dino", "Fiat 128", "Fiat X1-9", "Ford Pantera L", "Honda Civic", 
"Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Lincoln Continental", 
"Lotus Europa", "Maserati Bora", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Merc 230", "Merc 240D", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", 
"Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Pontiac Firebird", "Porsche 914-2", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Valiant", "Volvo 142E"), class = "factor"), 
    mpg = c(145, 120, 150, 132, 110, 98), cyl = c(93, 116, 114, 
    156, 148, 167), disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225), hp = c(110, 
    110, 93, 110, 175, 105)), .Names = c("Name", "mpg", "cyl", 
"disp", "hp"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

data 2:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(18L, 19L, 5L, 13L, 14L, 31L
), .Label = c("AMC Javelin", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Camaro Z28", 
"Chrysler Imperial", "Datsun 710", "Dodge Challenger", "Duster 360", 
"Ferrari Dino", "Fiat 128", "Fiat X1-9", "Ford Pantera L", "Honda Civic", 
"Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Lincoln Continental", 
"Lotus Europa", "Maserati Bora", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Merc 230", "Merc 240D", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", 
"Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Pontiac Firebird", "Porsche 914-2", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Valiant", "Volvo 142E"), class = "factor"), 
    mpg_1 = c(125, 133, 143, 141, 134, 238), cyl_1 = c(114, 153, 
    112, 136, 128, 155), disp_1 = c(113, 143, 144, 131, 431, 
    331), hp_1 = c(332, 221, 113, 331, 134, 151)), .Names = c("Name", 
"mpg_1", "cyl_1", "disp_1", "hp_1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to calculate the ratio between corresponding rows in a data sets. All the values from the row (4 columns) should be used for ratio calculation and ratio should be calculated between data sets. Using the simpler explanation:

```
data1[1,2] / data2[1,2]
data1[1,2] / data2[1,3]
...
data1[1,3] / data2[1,2]
...
```

I would like to store the results in separate data with columns labeled easily to recognize how the ratio was calculated.

Comment: Unsure of the relationship as your example data[1,2]/data2[1,3] is not elementwise?  You could easily just do `data1[,2:4] / data2[,2:4]` if you want elementwise math...

Comment: That's just an example. My real data is closely related. I would like to have a function which than I can easily implement in my real data. I would like to get al lcombinations. So ratio should be calculated between `mpg` and `disp_1`, `cyl` and `hp_1` and so on. All combinations.

Comment: Could you update with expected output i.e how is it different from output of `DF1[,-1]/DF2[,-1]`

Comment: I did explain in the comment. Number of ratios from one row will be more than 4.

Comment: `reshape2::melt(lapply(d1[-1], "/", d2[-1]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `lapply` you could do the following. With `rbind` you get long format and `cbind` results in wide format.

**Long Format:**

```
ratioLongDF = do.call(rbind,lapply(1:ncol(DF2[,-1]),function(x) 
         data.frame(DF1[,-1]/DF2[,-1][,x],divisor=colnames(DF2[,-1])[x] ) ) )


ratioLongDF
#         mpg       cyl      disp        hp divisor
#1  1.1600000 0.7440000 1.2800000 0.8800000   mpg_1
#2  0.9022556 0.8721805 1.2030075 0.8270677   mpg_1
#3  1.0489510 0.7972028 0.7552448 0.6503497   mpg_1
#4  0.9361702 1.1063830 1.8297872 0.7801418   mpg_1
#5  0.8208955 1.1044776 2.6865672 1.3059701   mpg_1
#6  0.4117647 0.7016807 0.9453782 0.4411765   mpg_1
#7  1.2719298 0.8157895 1.4035088 0.9649123   cyl_1
#8  0.7843137 0.7581699 1.0457516 0.7189542   cyl_1
#9  1.3392857 1.0178571 0.9642857 0.8303571   cyl_1
#10 0.9705882 1.1470588 1.8970588 0.8088235   cyl_1
#11 0.8593750 1.1562500 2.8125000 1.3671875   cyl_1
#12 0.6322581 1.0774194 1.4516129 0.6774194   cyl_1
#13 1.2831858 0.8230088 1.4159292 0.9734513  disp_1
#14 0.8391608 0.8111888 1.1188811 0.7692308  disp_1
#15 1.0416667 0.7916667 0.7500000 0.6458333  disp_1
#16 1.0076336 1.1908397 1.9694656 0.8396947  disp_1
#17 0.2552204 0.3433875 0.8352668 0.4060325  disp_1
#18 0.2960725 0.5045317 0.6797583 0.3172205  disp_1
#19 0.4367470 0.2801205 0.4819277 0.3313253    hp_1
#20 0.5429864 0.5248869 0.7239819 0.4977376    hp_1
#21 1.3274336 1.0088496 0.9557522 0.8230088    hp_1
#22 0.3987915 0.4712991 0.7794562 0.3323263    hp_1
#23 0.8208955 1.1044776 2.6865672 1.3059701    hp_1
#24 0.6490066 1.1059603 1.4900662 0.6953642    hp_1
```

**Wide Format:**

```
ratioWideDF = do.call(cbind,lapply(1:ncol(DF2[,-1]),function(x) {
              DF = data.frame(DF1[,-1]/DF2[,-1][,x] );
              colnames(DF)=paste0(colnames(DF),"_",colnames(DF2[,-1])[x]); 
              return(DF)} ) )   

ratioWideDF[,1:8]
#  mpg_mpg_1 cyl_mpg_1 disp_mpg_1  hp_mpg_1 mpg_cyl_1 cyl_cyl_1 disp_cyl_1  hp_cyl_1
#1 1.1600000 0.7440000  1.2800000 0.8800000 1.2719298 0.8157895  1.4035088 0.9649123
#2 0.9022556 0.8721805  1.2030075 0.8270677 0.7843137 0.7581699  1.0457516 0.7189542
#3 1.0489510 0.7972028  0.7552448 0.6503497 1.3392857 1.0178571  0.9642857 0.8303571
#4 0.9361702 1.1063830  1.8297872 0.7801418 0.9705882 1.1470588  1.8970588 0.8088235
#5 0.8208955 1.1044776  2.6865672 1.3059701 0.8593750 1.1562500  2.8125000 1.3671875
#6 0.4117647 0.7016807  0.9453782 0.4411765 0.6322581 1.0774194  1.4516129 0.6774194
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way using `expand.grid`, `rep`, and `mapply`. First, we use `expand.grid` to generate all the combinations of the columns we wish to iterate over. Then, we use `rep` to generate the rows we wish to iterate over. Then, we store these two values in a `data.frame`. Using the `mapply` function, we iterate through each row of `dat_iter` specifying the column and row indices we're interested in.

```
cols <- expand.grid(2:5, 2:5)
rows <- rep(1:6, each = 16)
dat_iter <- data.frame(rows, cols)
res <- t(mapply(x = dat_iter$rows, y = dat_iter$Var1, z = dat_iter$Var2,
       FUN = function(x, y, z) c('ratio' = data1[x, y] / data2[x, z],
                                 'd1_name' = names(data1)[y],
                                 'd2_name' = names(data2)[z],
                                 'row' = x)))

res[1:5,]

     ratio             d1_name d2_name row
[1,] "1.16"            "mpg"   "mpg_1" "1"
[2,] "0.744"           "cyl"   "mpg_1" "1"
[3,] "1.28"            "disp"  "mpg_1" "1"
[4,] "0.88"            "hp"    "mpg_1" "1"
[5,] "1.2719298245614" "mpg"   "cyl_1" "1"
```

Since we used `mapply`, you'll have to convert the first column to numeric.